# How can I change the style of this list?

Tags: html, css

I am quite noob to css so forgive me if my is a dumb question.
Given the image with the css class and id, how can I change the list style (the dots before the list and make them round)?

[image]

i'm trying writing like this:

```
#secondary.widget-area ul {
list-style-type: square;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Closed circle:

```
#secondary.widget-area ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Open circle:

```
#secondary.widget-area ul {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#secondary.widget-area ul {
list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add css margin-left:100px;in #secondary.widget-area ul ，if not ，May be the problem of selectot。